# scrapy Link Extractor Python Pagination

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

Link: https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/

When I scroll the page the Link gets changed to https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/page-2

on furthur scrolling, The link changes to https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/page-3 and so on.

The Link Extractor is only remaining scraps that get displayed only in first url i.e. https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/.

The Link Extractor Rule is as follows:

```
 rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='.flexWrap.flexStart.prw .thumb a[class="thmNm"]'),
         callback='parse_items',follow=True)
]
```

When the main link is calles using

```
  start_urls = [
    "https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/"
]
```

Only 50 Products get scrapped which are on page 1. Now there is no button or link for next for pagination.. The link gets updates on scrolling only and scrapy Link Extractor is not following the products that appear on scrolling and link changes i.e. When I scroll the page the Link gets changed to https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/page-2
and so on..

How to do this?   WHat do I need to change in Link Extractor Rule?

Comment: This type of question was answered many times. Search for "ajax infinite scroll".

Comment: Yeah But I need to do it using Restrict_css  in Link Extractors only. @SuperUser

Comment: @SuperUser I have checked Ajex infinite Scroll, It is a totally different concept I am doing it using Python.... Can you go through to check the Links and provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así puedes simular el scroll (especificamente para esta página)

```
start_urls= ['https://www.softsurroundings.com/clothing/tops/page-'+str(x)+'/' for x in range(1,3)]
```

De nada papu

Comment: Translation of the non-English part of your answer: "So you can simulate the scroll (specifically for this page)".  **Stack Overflow requires all posts to be written in English.**